# Can not read csv file, pandas parser error

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting parser error from pandas lib...not sure what could be the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/2020/python-nifi/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("C:\\2020\\test\\sum.csv", '\t')
  File "C:\2020\python-nifi\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\2020\python-nifi\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\2020\python-nifi\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\2020\python-nifi\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 860, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 875, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 929, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2071, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 4



import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("C:\\2020\\test\\sum.csv", sep='\t')
print(df)
```

file trying to read is ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXiOa.png)

Comment: The error is printed here `Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 4`, could assist better if you share a sample of your dataframe `df`

Comment: If you want, you can skip erroneous lines using: `pandas.read_csv(fileName, sep='delimiter' , error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: @ Cavin Dsouza, add the screenshot

Comment: @narendra-choudhary, you mean remove/escape pipe '|' in the cell?

Comment: after adding "error_bad_lines=False..got little different error..

Comment: after adding "error_bad_lines=False...  
libs\parsers.pyx", line 1084, in  pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_dataFile  pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1137, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1254, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtypeFile "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1269, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convertFile "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1459, in andas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd9 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

Comment: does the special character '|" making an issue?, which is mixed with column value. example... KG|ZB00000001|Nov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you use `df = pd.read_csv("filename", sep='[:,|_]',engine='python' )` ?
As you can use multiple seperators on import.

Comment: Thanks Karel, it was issue with the corrupted csv

Answer (score 0):

This error comes because of **encoding** error:

try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename', encoding='utf-8')
```